# Loaded JSON data not showing using $http GET on ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have recently started angularjs and I am trying to use ng-table to show the results from blast searches.

Adding the JSON data directly in the js script everything works fine.
Unluckily I could not succeed in loading a local JSON file using $http

I have alsready searched and found similar problems, but could not find a solution.

In particular a get this error from the debugger in Firefox:

> "Error: Access to restricted URI denied

follwed by the paths to angularjs libraries...

following is the code:

JS:

```
      var app = angular.module("main", ["ngTable", 'ngTableResizableColumns']);

  app.controller("DemoCtrl", ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', '$http', 'NgTableParams',  function($scope, $filter, $timeout, $http, NgTableParams){

    var data = [ ];

    $http.get('/cw2144_ecoli.json')
    .success(function(data, status, $scope) {

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          page: 1,            // show first page
          count: 10,          // count per page
          sorting: {
              blast_evalue: 'asc'    // initial sorting
          }
      }, {
          total: data.length, // length of data
          getData: function($defer, params) {
              // use built-in angular filter
              var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                      $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
                      data;
              var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                      $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                      data;

              params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
              $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
          }
      });

    });
  }]);
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="tableParams.sorting({})" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear sorting</button>
<button ng-click="tableParams.filter({})" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear filter</button>
<p><strong>Sorting:</strong> {{tableParams.sorting()|json}}
<p><strong>Filter:</strong> {{tableParams.filter()|json}}

<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table ng-table-resizable-columns table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Query'" sortable="'query_hdr'" filter="{ 'query_hdr': 'text' }">
            {{user.query_hdr}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Query Length'" sortable="'query_len'" filter="{ 'query_len': 'text' }">
            {{user.query_len}}
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "query_hdr": "Contig1013__1",
        "query_len": 54,
        "ncbi_bp_name": "Escherichia coli O127:H6 str. E2348/69",
        "fam_seq_func": "propanediol dehydratase, large subunit, AdoCbl-dependent",
        "fam_seq_prot_id": "CAS09680.1",
        "blast_pct_id": 71.7,
        "blast_score": 86.7,
        "blast_evalue": 1e-21,
        "ncbi_tax": 574521,
        "fam_id": 1001,
        "fam_pathogenicity": "yes",
        "fam_prob": 0.9991,
        "fam_seq_aln_cov_pct": 9.94
    },
    {
        "query_hdr": "Contig1026__1",
        "query_len": 55,
        "ncbi_bp_name": "Escherichia coli O104:H4 str. 2011C-3493",
        "fam_seq_func": "putative mercuric reductase",
        "fam_seq_prot_id": "AFS72021.1",
        "blast_pct_id": 100,
        "blast_score": 111,
        "blast_evalue": 2e-30,
        "ncbi_tax": 1133852,
        "fam_id": 954,
        "fam_pathogenicity": "yes",
        "fam_prob": 0.9391,
        "fam_seq_aln_cov_pct": 9.75
    }
]
```

This pobably simple think is really bugging me, you would make my day if you could solve it

Comment: What if you invoke link directly from the browser?

Comment: What are you using server side? IIS?

Comment: marianoc84, if you are talking about the json file, the browser is fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that this is an IIS issue. I had to add the following snippet to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are using an IIS, this may help.

Comment: Thank you MichaelS. First of I have to say I am not a webprogrammer. IN particular I am using no server-side application and trying to load the data from a locally stored JSON file. If you would have any different way to do it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Ok, then the error message makes sense. Most browser block access to local files for security reason. Does your code work in IE?

Comment: I am not planning to use IE. I am testing it on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Firefox and Safari behaves pretty much the same way. Testing in IE may help us finding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem a very simple one...
I just had to store the json file (or any other I was to have access to) in the same directory tree where the index.html (or main html file) lives.
For security reasons many browsers do not allow to access local files outside the above directory tree.

Thank you all for your suggestions and help